# Kentico transactions and rollback of data

Tags: parallel-processing, transactions, kentico

I am performing an import of data wrapped in a `CMSTransactionScope`.

What would be the most efficient and practical way to import data in parallel and rollback if any errors? The problem I see is that, with it being parallel, I don't know if I can have the inserted objects be part of the transaction if they are apart of a new thread.

Is there any way to do this or should it be handled differently?

Answer (score 1):

If you're running the code in parallel in order to achieve better performance and you are basically inserting rows one by one then it's unlikely that it'll perform any better than it would while running in a single thread.
In this case I'd recommend using **one** thread in combination with `CMSTransactionScope`, and potentially [`ConnectionHelper.BulkInsert`](http://devnet.kentico.com/articles/using-bulkinsert-to-import-data-in-kentico).

Anyway, if you still want to run your queries in parallel then you need to implement some kind of synchronization (locking, for instance) to ensure that all statements are executed before the code hits `CMSTransactionScope.Commit()` (this basically means a performance loss). Otherwise, queries would get executed in separate transactions. Moreover, you have to make sure that the `CMSTransactionScope` object always gets instantiated with the same `IDataConnection` (this should happen by default when you don't pass a connection to the constructor).

The second approach seems error prone to me and I'd rather take a look at different ways of optimizing the code (using async, etc.)

Comment: I can definitely understand and agree with you on the first approach for inserting data.

What about the updating of data? For instance, having a transactionscope and then looping in parallel updating rows one by one? I'm wondering if it is possible? Or would the kentico sql update query just deadlock because each thread has a new connection scope? Maybe i'm overthinking this ..

Comment: If you do e.g. a `Parallel.ForEach()` inside a `CMSTransactionScope` I believe that should work without any deadlocks. The transaction scope uses its own connection scope which, I hope, will get reused even when using multiple threads. However, I think the performance gain will be minimal, if any. The best way to find out is to go ahead an try it :)